# Select the same element multiple times using forxml?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, for-xml

I found an example of using `for xml` to create xml [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/12/sql-server-simple-example-of-creating-xml-file-using-t-sql/).

But in my case, I need to create xml that has multiple similar elements. Something like:

```
<params>
  <param>value1</param>
  <param>value2</param>
</param>
```

But if I try the following query:

```
SELECT (
  SELECT
'value1' AS [param],
'value2' AS [param]
FOR XML PATH('params'))
```

I end up with `<params><param>value1value2</param></params>` as my result. Not my desired output.

Any suggestions on how I could get the desired output?

Comment: do you want to use same param tag for both? Tr this - use `param2` as alias for `value2`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
-- An extra empty column in between
select
  'value1' AS [param],
  '',
  'value2' AS [param]
for xml path('params')

-- A derived table by using union all
select 'value1' union all
select 'value2'
for xml path('param'), root('params')

-- Subqueries in the field list
select
  (select 'value1' for xml path('param'), type),
  (select 'value2' for xml path('param'), type)
for xml path('params')
```